# Delete namespace and also delete Helm deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I deploy my Helm deploys to isolated namespaces.

Deleting a namespace deletes all the resources in it - except the Helm deployment.

Deleting a Helm deployment deletes all resource in it - except the namespace.

I have to do this which seems redundant:

```
helm del `helm ls NAMESPACE --short` --purge
kubectl delete namespace NAMESPACE
```

I'd rather just delete my namespace and have the Helm deploy also purged - is this possible?

Comment: Helm 3 now stores the metadata in the selected namespace, so it just works like that.

Answer (score 6):

> Deleting a namespace deletes all the resources in it- except the helm deployment

This can't be (deleting a namespace implies deleting everything in it, there aren't any exceptions), and must means that the state representing Helm's concept of a deployment doesn't live in that namespace. Helm stores these as config maps in the `TILLER_NAMESPACE`.  See [here](https://helm.sh/docs/architecture/#implementation) and [here](https://v3.helm.sh/docs/faq/#release-names-are-now-scoped-to-the-namespace).

It's not surprising that if you create some resources with `helm` and then go "under the hood" and delete those resources directly via `kubectl`, Helm's state of the world won't result in that deployment disappearing.

> Deleting a helm deployment deletes all resource in it- except the namespace

That sounds like expected behaviour. Presumably you created the namespace out of band with `kubectl`, it's not part of your Helm deployment. So deleting the Helm deployment wouldn't delete that namespace.

If you `kubectl create namespace NS` and `helm install CHART --namespace NS` then it's not surprising that to clean up, you need to `helm delete` the release and then `kubectl delete` the namespace.

The only way I could imagine to do that would be for the Helm chart itself to both create a namespace and create all subsequent namespace-scoped resources within that namespace. [Here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/5e00179b109d7290eb05a2b9705839fcf666d29a/stable/magic-namespace) is an example that appears to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PR created to cleanup all resources deployed from helm. follow the link --> https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1464

hopefully in the future release it will be addressed